# How write commands for Flutter Audio?

Tags: flutter, audio

I can't play the audio using these commands

```
final player = AudioCache();
player.play('note1.wav');
```

I have added the assets in the pubsec.yaml. What are the commands to run the audio in flutter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package [audioPlayer](https://pub.dev/packages/audioplayers)

And use following code

```
static final AudioPlayer _player = AudioPlayer(playerId: "id");
_player.play(url); /// if you use network url it play network url and if you add asset path it play asset audio
```